# Plot based on SliderTextInput that is based on radioButtons

Tags: r, shiny

df description:

A load was applied to a material repetitively, and the deformations were recorded in different locations on the material. Each repetition lasts 1 second, and the next repetition was right after the current one or after a resting period. Colnames are the chronological recorded seconds.

Each df has a different load rate (10kN, 20kN). The higher load was started after the lower one, and both end roughly at the same time.

shiny description:

I would like to have a shiny app that plots the deformation of the material. The user chooses the load rate by a radiobutton and a specific second the load was applied by a slider. The slider is updated according to the chosen load because each load is applied at different times.

When the user changes the load choice, the slider presents the last value it was on, then it is updated to the first value of the new df (as specified under "selected = ...").
That creates a temporary problem since the new df hasn't a colname with the previous slider value. The error "undefined columns selected" appears and disappears quickly after the slider is updated. Then the correct plot is displayed

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685364/shiny-error-message-undefined-column-selected-appears-after-loading-data-but-q) might has a similar problem, but all the offered solutions didn't work for me.

def10

```html
loc    1      2      21      22     45     46
0      -100   -95    -99     -94    -122   -110
200    -90    -88    -87     -84    -113   -106
400    -81    -70    -76     -73    -98    -94
600    -62    -59    -65     -61    -87    -83
```

def20

```html
loc    33     34     40      41     46     47
0      -144   -139   -141    -137   -142   -133
200    -134   -130   -132    -128   -131   -124
400    -122   -118   -120    -115   -121   -114
600    -111   -106   -108    -103   -107   -100
```

ui.R:

```html
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId = "Load", 
               label = "Select Load",
               choices = list("10kN" = 10, 
                              "20kN" = 20),
               selected = 10),
               
  uiOutput("sliderCycle"),
  
  plotOutput("defPlot")
)
```

server.R:

```html
shinyServer <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$sliderCycle <- renderUI({
    if (input$Load == 10) {
      sliderTextInput(inputId = "sliderCycle",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = colnames(def10[,2:ncol(def10)]),
                      selected = names(def10)[2])}
    else if (input$Load == 20) {
      sliderTextInput(inputId = "sliderCycle",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = colnames(def20[,2:ncol(def20)]),
                      selected = names(def20)[2])}
  })
  
  dfStatLoad <- reactive({
    if (input$Load == 10) {
      def10}
    else if (input$Load == 20) {
      def20}
  })
  
  defData <- reactive({
    data.frame(location = dfStatLoad()$loc, deformation = dfStatLoad()[,input$sliderCycle])
  })

  output$defPlot <- renderPlot({
    # the slider is NULL at first
    validate( 
      need(input$sliderCycle, "loading data...")) 
    ggplot(defData(), aes(location, deformation)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line()
   })

  # to check what values I get in the console
  checkcon <- reactive({
    print(input$Load) 
    print(input$sliderCycle)
  }) 
  observe(print(checkcon()))

}
```

The console prints the following:

```html
[1] "10" # run app
NULL     # slider is empty
NULL     # again (why?)
[1] "10" # again Load choice
[1] "1"  # updated slider value
[1] "1"  # again (why?)
[1] "20" # user chooses "20kN"
[1] "1"  # previous slider value
[1] "1"  # again (why?)
[1] "20" # again Load choice
[1] "33" # updated slider value
[1] "33" # again (why?)
```

Why does the slider have a double input? Why isn't it updated immediately?

Thank you for reading and answering!